# removeClass from previous event.target

Tags: events, target, removeclass

I am trying to add a class to a `<li>` element on a click event and then remove that class on the subsequent click of another element in the same `<ul>`.  No problem adding the class but I've tried a number of approaches, unsuccessfully to remove the class.

```
<ul>
  <li  class="show" id="all">All Posts</li>
  <li  class="show" id="user" data-user="7">My Posts</li>
  <li  class="show" id="follow">Following</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("li").click(function(event) {

    var name = event.target.className;
var newclass = 'choice';
  //console.log(name);

if($(event.target)) {
  $(event.target).addClass(newclass);
  }

if(!$(event.target)) {
  $('li').each(function() {
        $('.' + name + '.' + newclass).removeClass(newclass);
    })
}

$('.'+ name + "." + newclass).attr('style','background-color:yellow');

//console.log(name);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you only need `.siblings()`:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('choice');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('choice');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Category: Event Object jQuery’s event system normalizes the event
>   object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to
>   be passed to the event handler.

And:

> event.target The DOM element that initiated the event.

And:

> jQuery() — which can also be written as $()

```
jQuery( element ) 
element Type: Element A DOM element to wrap in a jQuery object.
```

So how can $(event.target) ever be false?  event.target is a DOM element that you are wrapping in a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks much. I see what you are saying about wrapping a DOM element in a JQuery object. Need to do more work on that sort of thing.